# Stop Applications Loading

Tags: task-management, auto-start

How can I stop so many applications loading, and slowing down the system. When I clear the Ram I usually see that at least 16 applications have been running. What for?

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps out there which will help you know which apps are running in background and hogging resources with extra features from stock task manager. Few of good apps are

[**Elixir 2**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmJhcnRhdC5hbmRyb2lkLmVsaXhpciJd)-Application Monitoring Manager.

[**Wake Lock Detector**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector)-Tells you which apps are keeping your phone in partial awake or in full awake state.

[**Advanced Task Manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=EN&id=mobi.infolife.taskmanager)-Will help you manage running processes.

Stay away from task killer apps they are no good and  drain out battery.